# Any way to preserve leading or trailing white space in an apex:inputText?

Tags: visualforce

I have a page where the user can specify a prefix or suffix. By the time the value is available in the controller leading and trailing white space has been removed. This is usually helpful but not in this case as a user might want the "Name" prefixed with "Pre " resulting in "Pre Name" or "Pre-" resulting in "Pre-Name".

Any ideas on how to keep the leading or trailing white space for a couple of fields in a Visualforce page?

Comment: How about `<apex:input>` bound to helper string variable (can't bind it to sObject fields)? Or inputTextarea with 1 row and 50(?) cols?

Comment: @eyescream Current code binds to a String not an SObject field and leading/trailing space is stripped. Not clear how inputTextarea would help: am I wrong in assuming leading/trailing whitespace would be stripped there too?

Comment: I saw some correctly formatted CaseComments & Task descriptions in my previous employee's org (they were pasting some logs from network issue debugging programs). I've just built them a page that had `<pre>` and some whitespace-related CSS; the page merged comments, emails, activities, field history & chatter into 1 giant "feed" sorted by timestamp and they were quite happy to see it formatting like in command line console... Worth trying?

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work. Retains whitespace in the middle of the string but strips everything in front and back... Javascript "onchange/onblur" piece that'd copy the value to hidden helper field and replace spaces with something that's unlikely to be inserted by your users? Some obscure ASCII char or "replace underscore with 2 underscores; replace spaces with underscore"?

Comment: @eyescream Yeah if no-one offers a simple solution maybe a JavaScript replace with say a non-breaking space on submit on the client-side and the reverse on the server-side.